# Does F# have a way to print the type of an expression?

Tags: f#

I'm looking for the moral equivalent of `ghci`'s:

```
Prelude> :t 1 + 2
1 + 2 :: Num a => a
```

Comment: Doesn't it already do this by default?  For example `1;;` produces `val it : int = 1`

Comment: @JohnPalmer - that's handy but not quite the same.  Consider `(+)`, which will not show a properly generic type signature.  Or take an expression like `deleteDatabase()`, which you might want to find the type of without executing it.

Comment: @kvb Well, in the case of `deleteDatabase()` you could still type `deleteDatabase;;`

Comment: also you usually have those nice *tooltips* (in VS, MonoDevelop - heck even in emacs with the bindings ;) )

Comment: @kvb also: `(+)` is not really that generic in F# (not like what you might know from Haskell) - `let inline plus a b = a + b;;` on the other side ... well you get my point ;)

Comment: @Carsten - if anything it's more generic than Haskell's, since the types of the operands and return type need not match (e.g. consider `(+) System.DateTime.Now (System.TimeSpan.FromSeconds 1.0)`).

Comment: @kvb well no, you did not get my point - .net's type system is just not prepared for that kind of thing - yeah the `+` operator can have different types of arguments (something the designers of `Num` in Haskell choose not to do, but that does not mean that you cannot have such an generic operator in Haskell) - in .net on the otherside the operators are quite *hard-coded* and the things F# provide over this (the stuff with inline I mentioned above) are compiler *tricks* that will vanish in the compiled IL

Comment: don't get me wrong: I **love** F# (and I am so glad I can use it daily) but there are certain things in Haskell (type-system is on big) that are just *damn* better than in F# and fanboy or not, I just cannot overlook those - it's not the languages nor the designers fault - we want to interop with .net and that means certain compromises have to been made (btw: of course there are things that F# does better than Haskell - records for example ;) )

Comment: @Carsten - You're right that the .NET representation of F# types and expressions is coarser than the F#-level representation, but I don't believe that's relevant.  Just as hovering over `+` gives a tooltip `val (+) : x:'T1 -> y:'T2 -> 'T3 (requires member (+))`, one could easily build a REPL directive that resulted in the same information when given the expression (and that appears to be what the OP asks for).  However, entering a bare expression at the REPL does not, in general, produce that result, so it is not (in all cases) a suitable replacement for such a feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In F# Interactive you get that after each execution:

```
> (+);;
val it : (int -> int -> int) = <fun:it@1>
> 1 + 2;;
val it : int = 3
> printfn "Hi";;
Hi
val it : unit = ()
```

Comment: As I stated in a comment on the question, this is a helpful technique but is not a true replacement for Haskell's feature, both because the evaluation of an expression may cause side effects and also because the value restriction can cause results to be less generic than the expressions themselves might be in other contexts (or may even make certain expressions invalid as top-level values).

Comment: It does seem to be the only "moral equivalent" though. I'm going to make this answered. Thanks! What's more is that it still works with side-effecty code like `printfn`.